# Skip stepper connecting lines with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a stepper component built with React. The component takes in an array of steps, and it accepts an array of indexes of disabled steps to skip on them. I want to have the skip dotted line in a manner as shown below using CSS.

[image]

The stepper I have built:

[image]

Expected using CSS:

[image]

The code is here in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xum4he)

Please navigate to **Step.jsx** for the styles.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add .skip class for the particular li element and add below css aswell

CSS

```
.skip:before{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: So in my case, for the step 2 li tag, I add the skip class right?

Comment: I added it, but it doesnt seem to take effect. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xum4he

Comment: Please inspect it and see that the class .skip is added to the second li tag

Comment: So I added the class to the li elements which are not disabled and it did the trick

Comment: Are you able to get it? I kinda lost the styles all of a sudden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202083/discussion-between-a2441918-and-par-tha).

Comment: check it here its working https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mkgyos

Comment: I have this case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zrw1xs?file=Stepper.jsx

Is there a way to concatenate both into a single connection?